# How can I import Elasticsearch data into Microsoft Fabric?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to connect Elasticsearch with Microsoft fabric.

I have connected on elasticsearch gateway. Which process I should use to get data from elasticsearch to fabric. should I use REST or HTTP for getting Data? What are best steps to process the elasticsearch data